# when getting data from xml file, get missing value if node is missing

Tags: r, xml, rvest

I have the following problem:

```
library(xml2)

test_xml <- "
<test>
<Trial>
<ID> 1 </ID>
<plouf> plouf </plouf>
</Trial>
<Trial>
<ID> 2 </ID>
</Trial>
</test>"

test <- as_xml_document(test_xml)
```

When I do :

```
test %>%
  xml_find_all("//plouf") %>%
  xml_text()
```

I only get

```
[1] " plouf "
```

How can I get a vector of same length than the initial xml (here 2), with missing value when the node `<plouf>` is absent from `<Trial>`?

Comment: Are you after a single vector or transforming XML document into a flat data.frame?

Comment: transforming xml doc into flat data.frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first extract only the `<Trial>` nodes and then use `xml_find_first()` to extract `<plouf>` nodes from them. Unlike `xml_find_all()`, `xml_find_first()` returns a missing node when there is no match so you will get `NA` when there is no `<plouf>`.

```r
test %>%
  xml_find_all("//Trial") %>%
  xml_find_first("plouf") %>%
  xml_text()
# [1] " plouf " NA
```

Answer (score 1):

When working towards a data.frame / tibble, and in this particular case, you could first build a nodeset of all `Trial` nodes and turn that into a list. The list generated from the provided sample can be turned into a nested tibble with `bind_rows()`, which can be passed to `unnest(everything())` . For more complex XML structures rectangling usually takes quite a few more steps, often a series of `unnest_longer()` / `unnest_longer()` operations and/or more specific XPath expressions than just `.//node` .

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(xml2)

test_xml <- "
<test>
    <Trial>
        <ID> 1 </ID>
        <plouf> plouf </plouf>
    </Trial>
    <Trial>
        <ID> 2 </ID>
    </Trial>
</test>"

test <- read_xml(test_xml)

test |> 
  xml_find_all(".//Trial") |>
  as_list() |>
  bind_rows() |>
  unnest(everything())
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   ID    plouf    
#>   <chr> <chr>    
#> 1 " 1 " " plouf "
#> 2 " 2 "  <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>